# An infinite summation involving spherically symmetric eigenfunctions of the heat equation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, summation

I need help solving for the $C_n$ in the following infinite sum:

$$−\sin(\pi r) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n\frac{\sin(n \pi r)}{r}\cdot e^{-n^{2}\pi^{2} t}$$

I have been trying to solve this for a while and my solutions do not satisfy the equality.

$r$ is defined on $1\leq r \leq 2$.

$−\sin(\pi r)$ is the sum evaluated at $t = 0$.

Any tips or pointers for how to solve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: So what you're asking for is the $C$s satisfying $-r \sin(\pi r) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\,C_n \sin(n\pi r)$. Is $r$ bounded? If so take advantage of 
 the orthogonality of the Fourier basis.

Comment: $r$ is defined on the domain $1\leq r \leq2$